# is there any advantage in using int instead of float without decimal numbers?

Tags: c#, floating-point, int

Is there any advantage in using int instead of float when the number you want to store isn't a decimal number?

eg.

```
int number = 10;
float number = 10;
```

Why  would I want to use an int instead of a float here?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, there are lots of advantages.

- Arithmetic on `int`s is much faster.
- `int`s will never suffer from precision loss.
- People reading your code will know that the variable is actually an integer.
- It will not be possible to accidentally put a non-integer in the variable

Comment: Can a float suffer from precision loss within the range of int when representing an integer?

Comment: +1... there are also a lot of disadvantages (like less obvious overflow behavior, need of conversions for most of complex math functions, inflexible rounding on division) but the question is about advantages :)

Comment: Isn't `int a = 1 / 2;` an (evil) example of precision loss?

Comment: @Chamster well...     int a = 1/2 = 0 float a = 1/2f = 0.5 (which I think can be represented exactly by a float) also good reference for floating point http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/FloatingPoint.aspx

Comment: @SLaks Haha, I agree with you totally. He **should** use `int` in this case. I only meant that **if** we could find **something** to object, you could get **sort of** precision loss. It was mostly a joke. :)

Comment: Are ints really faster in our times?

Comment: @AminNegm-Awad: Yes; integer arithmetic is fundamentally much simpler than floating point.  However, unless you're doing _lots_ of math, it won't matter.

Comment: @SLaks I know, that it is fundamentally simpler. But I did not ask that. Think of modern CPUs.

Comment: @AminNegm-Awad: Modern CPUs do not magically make complex operations faster than simple ones.  Yes; floats are much faster than they used to be, but ints are _even more_ much faster than they used to be.

Comment: First of all, I did not say, that floating point arithmetic is faster. I said (doubt), that It is not slower. The set of arithmetic operations you can do on ints in C are really executed slower on a modern CPU? Are you sure? Really? Did you check it?

Answer (score 4):

for one because int math is faster. A better question to ask is why would you want to use type A to represent something you know is of type B?

In general you should use the type that matches what you are trying to represent

Answer (score 2):

1. Ints are faster
2. When you are declaring huge number of ints, ints may save memory (nevertheless it depends on other factors as well)
3. Conceptual, for instance number of people cannot be float right?!

Comment: Number of children in the "average" family, per the U.S. 2000 census data, was 1.86 which fell to 1.14 in the 2010 census. <g>

Comment: I meant number of people in a family and not average number of people, it is very obvious to use double data type for floats, I would expect a better comment from a guy with reputation 3733 :)

Answer (score 1):

- Int is faster for calculations
- Int is exact in the range it works for
- Floats have a vastly larger range of possible, less precise, values 
  (int from -2147483648 to 2147483647)
  (float from -3.402823E+38 to 3.402823E+38)